# eplain access to \li number

Tags: tex-core, eplain

What is the best way to get the "marker" for the current item in a list in the eplain format?

```
\numberedlist
  \li Here's an item
  \li And this is another and it's marker is: \marker
\endnumberedlist
```

I've tried using "\marker" but from what I can tell, by the time that is expanded, the item number has already been incremented.  I tried reading the eplain.tex source but I'm not proficient enough to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`eplain` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/eplain/doc/eplain.pdf) says in section "4.6 Lists":

> You can give `\li` an optional argument, a cross-reference label. It’s
>   defined to be the "marker" for the current item. This is useful if the
>   list items are numbered. You can produce the value of the label with
>   `\xrefn`. See Section 4.9 [Cross-references], page 15.

Applied to the example:

```
\numberedlist
  \li Here's an item
  \li[this] And this is another and it's marker is: \xrefn{this}
  \li A third item
\endnumberedlist
\bye
```

The result after two `eplain` runs:

> [image: Result]

With `\enablehyperlinks` the reference will actually become a link.

Comment: Thanks, Heiko.  I was aware of that mechanism but for some reason it didn't occur to me to use it "within" the \li.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with two alternative solutions.

Using e-tex's \numexpr:

```
\def\currentitemnum{\the\numexpr \number\itemnumber-1 \relax}

\numberedlist
  \li Here's an item
  \li And this is another and it's marker is: \currentitemnum
  \li A third item
\endnumberedlist

\bye
```

...And another using the xint package:

```
\input xint.sty \relax

\def\currentitemnum{\xintDec{\number\itemnumber}}

\numberedlist
  \li Here's an item
  \li And this is another and it's marker is: \currentitemnum
  \li A third item
\endnumberedlist

\bye
```

Comment: With release `1.1` from `2014/10/28` of `xint` there is smaller package `xintcore` which already contains `\xintDec`. This being said, your first proposal is the better one, as ultimately `\xintDec` boils down to it (`\xintDec` is able to handle arbitrarily big numbers but `\numexpr` can't go beyond `2147483647`). In the first method (but not the second), you don't actually need `\number`.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this thread was tagged as eplain but I mean that it would be useful to show the same problem solved in OPmac only for comparison. OPmac is another simple macro package based on plain TeX like eplain.

First. The mentioned problem doesn't occur, because `\itemnum` has its current value:

```
\input opmac

\begitems \style n
* This is first item.
* This second item has a number \the\itemnum.
* This is the last item.
\enditems

\bye
```

[image: items]

Of course, you can add the reference stuff for the item in the list too:

```
\input opmac

\begitems \style n
* This is first item.
* \label[this]\wlabel{\the\itemnum}This second item has its number.
* This is the last item.
\enditems

The item \ref[this] is mentioned at the page \pgref[this].
% prints as: The item 2 is mentioned at the page 1.

\bye
```

If you declare `\hyperlinks\Blue\Blue` then the references will actually become a link.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to OPmac.  I shall definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of \wlabel?  It is not mentioned in the opmac manual and I'm afraid my TeX coding skills aren't yet sufficient to understand the source code.

Comment: The `\wlabel{text}` creates the connection between `text` and previously declared label. When you type `\ref[label]` then `text` is printed. Because you can type `\ref[label]` *before* the referenced object then `\wlabel` writes data to the `*.ref` file.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I wonder why the definition of "\startitem" doesn't include this, similar to \chap, \sec, etc?

Comment: You can set arbitrary text for references by `\wlabel`, for example `\wlabel{\the\itemnum}`, `\wlabel{\athe\itemnum)}`, `wlabel{item (\romannumeral\itemnum)}` or whatever you want.

Comment: After a week or so looking at OPmac, I must say I really like it!  For someone just learning TeX the code is remarkably understandable and easy to modify.  Thanks P.Olsak aka wipet!

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry that the technical documentation in `opmac-d.pdf` file extensively comments all OPmac macros only in the Czech language which is understandable for two promiles of population only. This is my fault.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but what would it take for a translation?  Also, CTAN lists CSPlain as "csplain – Plain TeX support for Czech/Slovak typesetting", when in reality seems more like "a Plain TeX format that provides convenient macro support for font handling with both 8-bit TeX engines as well as 16-bit engines (LuaTeX/XeTeX).  Additionally, has custom support for Czech/Slovak as well as hyphenation support for 50+ other languages."

Comment: I only found CSPlain because of OPMac and considering how useful the font handling is in CSPlain, its a shame that many non Czech/Slovak users may be unaware of it's existence and utility.

Comment: There is an article about CSplain (New Csplain of 2012) published in TUGboat 34/No 1. The article about OPmac is in the same issue too.

Comment: ... what would be take for a translation? ... I am thinking in Czech and my ideas are more fast than the translation effort. First discussion similar this were about my book "TeXbook naruby" 14 years ago.

Comment: There is another important feature of CSplain. If TeX od pdfTeX is used then CSplain treats the UTF-8 input by encTeX, i.e. without any active characters. The declaration of any number of UTF-8 characters is possible. For example `\input cyrchars` `This is a text на русском языке.` `\bye` works in pdfTeX+csplain without any explicit font switcher and any active characters.